# Create a type in Typescript that can be one of specific list of React components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create an array of components, the type of which must be limited to a few specific components:

```
const heroProps: HeroSectionProps = { ... }
const someOthercomponentProps: SomeOtherComponentProps = { ... }

const sections: Section[] = [<Hero {...heroProps} key="sectionheroasdfg" />, 
                             <SomeOtherComponent {...someOtherComponentProps} key="asddfasfa" />
                            ]
```

My problem is in defining the right type for `Section`, here are a few things that I have tried:

```
type Section = React.FC<HeroSectionProps> | React.FC<SomeOtherSectionProps>
```

I also tried:

```
type Section = typeof Hero | typeof SomeOtherComponent
```

Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concatenate the classes

```
type Section = Hero | SomeOtherComponent
```

Comment: that doesnt work either, when I do this it complains: `"Hero" refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Hero'?` and typeof Hero doesnt work either

Comment: Is Hero a type, or do you have a Hero variable/constant in there?

Comment: Hero is a component, its type is React.FC<HeroSectionProps> at least thats the type I gave it when I created the component, but that does not work either.

Comment: `Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Section'.
  Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' provides no match for the signature '(props: PropsWithChildren<HeroSectionProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any>'.`